# Xamarin - Event when translateto is finished

Tags: xamarin, animation

I have some animations running at the same time with different time length so awaiting is not my best option ...

How can I wait for the animation to be completed?
something in these lines:

```
accepted.TranslateTo(
        newX, newY,
        1500, Easing.CubicIn,
        (o,e) => {
             accepted.MakeGlow();
         } 

rejected.TranslateTo(
    HazardsDeckDiscard.X, 
    HazardsDeckDiscard.Y, 
    300, 
    Easing.CubicIn,
    (o,e) => {
               RemoveFromScreen(rejected);
             }
    );
```

Comment: What is its specific execution logic, and what execution sequence should it be in?

Comment: as stated in the pseudocode example. When the accepted item finies to translate to its new position it should glow (via MakeGlow method).
At the same time the rejected item should move to a dofiferent position, way faster and when there it should dissapear (via RemoveFromScreen)

Comment: If you want the same time. Try changing 300 to 1500.

Comment: I do want different times.  for the rejected item I want a short animation, then delete it. For the selected item I want a long animation then glow. When I said "at the same time" I meant they both start at the same time. But one finishes earlier than the other.

Comment: Do you want to end at the same time when two methods are triggered at the same time?

Comment: both methods are triggered at the same time. one takes 1500ms and the other 300ms. So they finish at different times

Comment: Since you are writing the dead time, you cannot stop at the same time. Unless you write a method for simultaneous triggering, set the same end time.

Comment: so you are saying there is no way to get notified when each separated animation is finished? Is really hard to believe..

Comment: Because your requirement is to trigger at the same time, but one of the two methods you define is 300 and the other is 1500. If it is impossible to run at the same time and end at the same time, I suggest that you can create a new method to use when triggering at the same time.